# Compile assets before publish a gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems, coffeescript, assets

I'm working on small project https://github.com/lucassus/mongo_browser
It's an application written in sinatra.rb framework along with simple assets pipeline for compiling coffeescript and sass. Since the app is published as gem I had to add `sprockets`, `coffee-script` and `sass` to gem's runtime dependency.

This solution has some significant drawbacks:

- an endpoint user has to install all those dependencies
- he has to have a JavaScript runtime installed (nodejs for example)
- app is slightly slow because of assets compilation

The big question is: Is it possible to distribute compiled assets inside the gem?

Moreover, I don't want to store compiled assets inside the repo and I want to compile them only during gem package process. Kind of gem package hook or sth?

Comment: I read somewhere you can embed gems so it's totally possible.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, add them to `files=`. For the compilation, add the logic to the `.gemspec`, at the beginning. It's just ruby, after all.